# Pass open connection between two different python programs

Tags: python

Pass open connection between two different python programs

Here is my use case..

I want to connect to ssh server ( network / linux/ windows) and open the connection.
And have another python program continue to use open session from step 1 and provide user inputs (commands )
The reason programs have to be separate is the caller is going to orchestrate these programs into a graphical process flow inside a designer workflow e.g mistral.

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why exactly can't the second program initiate its own SSH session?

Answer (score 2):

CAN I PASS THE HANDLE OF WHATEVER? **NO** (I'm pretty sure at least)

... why not just pass the credentials and let it open connection?

or basically your first program would have to run some sort of server, that listens for commands and forwards them up the tree ... something like this i guess

one way of passing information between two applications might be to have a flask server running on one and the other calls the flask endpoints (you dont have to use flask ... theres many ways to do this)

```
import argparse
import requests
from flask import Flask,request

def prog_1():
    ''' manage some open connection '''
    my_open_thing = OpenConnection(stuff)
    app = flask.Flask("__main__")
    @app.route("/execute"):
    def execute_command():
        if request.form.get("CMD",None):
           my_open_thing.send(request.form['CMD'])
           return my_open_thing.recv().to_string()
    app.run(port=23123)

def prog_2():
    '''interact with other thing'''
    while 1:
      cmd = input("CMD:")
      if cmd in ["quit","q"]:
         break
      print(requests.post("http://localhost:23123/execute",{"CMD":cmd}).content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('TYPE',choices=['manager','client'],help="Serve the connection, or use the manager")
    parser.parse_args()
    if parser.TYPE == "manager":
        prog_1()
    else:
        prog_2()
```

Comment: I think I know what he's asking.  He's talking about a SSH session handle rather than a file handle, but since the syntax for the latter is more familiar, I'll use it as an example.  He wants to do `filehandle = open ("somefile.txt", "w")` in one Python program, and then pass **filehandle** to another Python program so that it can use that handle to write stuff into "somefile.txt".  He wants to do this, but with a ssh session handle (I think). - is this right @jongull?

Comment: i think your right ... but the only way(**i think**) is for the first program to provide access to its handle methods .... via some mechanism... if my assumption is wrong i think this question becomes much more interesting

Comment: So isn't the answer really a clean "No" in the strict sense of the question?  In other words, to use my example, there's no way he can call `f.write()` in the second program, on a "passed over" file handle where what's being called is the standard Python file write() method, right?  ...and same answer for a SSH session handle?

Comment: ...and sorry if I'm wasting way too much time on this wacky question.

Comment: @steve yes you got it right, I need first program to open the connection and second and subsequent programs to use connection object from first program. The reason for this specific requirement is the python programs will be wrapped in something called actions and constructed into workflow tasks and its important for me to be able to use existing connectino than opening a new one.

Comment: Ok...well, I don't there's any way to do that.